# Deserializing JSON

Tags: json, f#

I'm trying to deserialize a relative simple JSON string, which looks like:

```
[{
    "FacebookID": "00000000000000",
    "Items": [{
        "BillID": "75a9ca7b-3b79-4db0-9867-83b2f66021d2",
        "FacebookID": "0000000000",
        "Description": "Some description",
        "Amount": 5000,
        "Accepted": false
    }]
}, {
    "FacebookID": "00000000000000",
    "Items": [{
        "BillID": "cec0a6d2-1db9-4a12-ae43-f61c6c69f0a6",
        "FacebookID": "0000000000",
        "Description": "Some description",
        "Amount": 3250,
        "Accepted": false
    }, {
        "BillID": "aaf51bb3-4ae6-48b5-aeb6-9c4d42fd4d2a",
        "FacebookID": "0000000000",
        "Description": "Some more..",
        "Amount": 100,
        "Accepted": false
    }]
}, {
    "FacebookID": "0000000000",
    "Items": [{
        "BillID": "2124cbc4-2a48-4ba4-a179-31d4191aab6a",
        "FacebookID": "0000000000",
        "Description": "even more..",
        "Amount": 300,
        "Accepted": false
    }]
}]
```

nothing fancy as you see.. except for the `Items` array, but that shouldnt really be a problem.

If we then make up a few types that matches the json-string, and a function that will deserialize the string and map it to the types we'll end up with something like:

```
[<DataContract>]
type Item = 
  { [<field: DataMember(Name = "BillID")>]
    BillID : string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "FacebookID")>]
    FacebookID : string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "Description")>]
    Description : string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "Amount")>]
    Amount : int
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "Accepted")>]
    Accepted : bool }

[<DataContract>]
type Basic = 
  { [<field: DataMember(Name = "FacebookID")>]
    FacebookID : string 
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "Items")>]
    Items : Item array }

// My function to deserialize the json string, and map it to the given type.
let deserializeJson<'a> (s:string) =
  use ms = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes s)
  let serialize = DataContractSerializer(typeof<'a>)
  serialize.ReadObject ms :?> 'a

let get (url:string) =
  use web = new WebClient()
  web.DownloadString url

// Returns the JSON string
let result = deserializeJson<Basic array> <| get "http://some.com/blabla"
```

Instead of doing its job, it simply throws following exception, when it's trying to deserialize the string:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException:
>   There was an error deserializing the
>   object of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList`1
>   [[Program+Basic, ConsoleApplication1,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKe yToken=null]]. The data at
>   the root level is invalid. Line 1,
>   position 1.

Am I missing something? - The JSON-string is perfectly valid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serializer you are using is for XML you want to use [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx).

Comment: You're right. I had that in my "real code".. not sure how I managed to get it wrong for this post. Anyway, even with an array of `Basic` it's still throwing same exception. (updated the post to array instead now) - Thanks for pointing that out :)